# Setting wmode="transparent" doesn't work with Flex app and SWFObject?

Tags: apache-flex, swfobject, transparent, wmode

I am using SWFObject to embed a Flex (4.1 SDK) made application in an HTML page like in the code sample below:

```
var swfVersionStr="10.0.0";
var xiSwfUrlStr="playerProductInstall.swf";
var flashvars={};
var params={};
params.quality="high";
params.bgcolor="#FFFFFF";
params.wmode="transparent";
params.menu="false";
params.allowscriptaccess="sameDomain";
params.allowfullscreen="true";
var attributes={};
attributes.id="vp";
attributes.name="vp";
attributes.align="middle";
swfobject.embedSWF("vp.swf","flashContent","624","451",swfVersionStr,xiSwfUrlStr,flashvars,params,attributes);
```

Why isn't the transparency of the Flash background occuring?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, apparently you need to implement a custom skin for your spark Application and set the rectangle's solid color fill's alpha to be 0...

Here's one that needs to be fixed ASAP, Flex Team. :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice spotting,
I have just added `bgRectFill.alpha = getStyle('backgroundAlpha');`.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    bgRectFill.color=getStyle('backgroundColor');
    bgRectFill.alpha=getStyle('backgroundAlpha');
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you’ve specified a background colour…

```
params.bgcolor="#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: It's always worked with that specified, and I have tried removing it, clearing cache and refresing but still the same. I've even put the `wmode` parameter on top of `bgcolor` and still nothing.

Comment: It must be a Flex 4.1 specific issue.